# GitLab CI runner not finding file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

My scripts can't be found even though echoing the path and files in the runner show it is indeed there.

[image]

[image]

Anything else I can try?  At a loss here.  Thanks.

Comment: This appears to be an error occurring in your script. Can you provide the contents of your script?